# В sentry не пишет ошибки, как найти причину?

Tags: php

Поставил и настроил sentry  [по инструкции](http://www.volmed.org.ru/wiki/index.php/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_Sentry_+_Apache_+_Mysql). sentry запустилось. Создал проект настроил.

Запускаю код для проверки:

```
$client = new Raven_Client('Ключ API');
// записать простое сообщение
$client->captureMessage('hello world!');
// перехватить исключение
try {
    throw new Exception('Uh oh!');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $client->captureException($e);
}
```

Тут вроде все сработало, с сервера приходит ответ в виде

```
{'id':'dsafdsgly89ysdiufgsd87fgsdiv'}
```

Но в sentry нет ни одной записи, в базе тоже нет никаких изменений, искал логи с ошибками - тоже безрезультатно. Запускал скрипт Raven_Client как с сервера, так и локально. Подскажите, где искать, может, чего-то не хватает в инструкции или в самом проекте нужна тонкая настройка?

Comment: Если внутри sentry происходят ошибки, то они добавляются в базу данных, но из вне не добавляется